# ajax json_encode returns null for thai, arabic and chinese characters

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter, multilingual

I am working with multilingual(asian languages) website, and facing strange problem. I have a function which return string wrapped in json_encode.

I am using **codeigniter** and i have set

> $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
>
> $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

If i **directly print output then it displays** chinese, arabic, thai string properly that means i have properly coded my webpage and php to print multilingual string, but **if i fetch that string via ajax and use json_encode it prints '??????'**

So far i tried

1. Adding "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE" to json_encode function. (server throws error for this, php5 doesnt support this i guess)
2. Adding UTF header just before json_encode function
3. Also tried setting UTF header in ajax request
4. Even tried adding

> mb_convert_encoding($reviewsui, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');

but nothing worked so far. Did i miss anything ?

**Edit**
I even tried to pass that string through **utf8_encode()** that didnt solved my problem even. The only difference i saw is instead of "????" i see "à¤¸à¤®à¤¾à¤ à¤ªà¤°".

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` expects strings in the data to be encoded as `UTF-8.`

Convert them to `UTF-8` if they aren't already.Have a look at below example

```
  $results = array_map(function($r) {
      $r['text'] = utf8_encode($r['text']);
      return $r;
    }, $results);
    echo json_encode($results);
```